# How to hide home title on pages and posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, posts

i want to delete home title, also main website title on pages and posts.
I i set a title for website "blablabla"

and when i crate a posts or pages with name "hello world"

The actual title of that post or page is "hello world | blablabla"

But i want to delete this | blablabla
is it possible?

i Found this in theme, how should i modify it?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'heatmapthemead_wp_title' ) ):

    function heatmapthemead_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
        global $paged, $page;

        if ( is_feed() )
            return $title;

        // Add the site name.
        $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

        // Add the site description for the home/front page.
        $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
            $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

        // Add a page number if necessary.
        if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
            $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'heatmapthemead' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

        return $title;
    }

endif; // heatmapthemead_wp_title

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'heatmapthemead_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Do you mean title in `<title>` tag? You can change it using SEO plugins like All in One SEO Pack or Yoast SEO.

Comment: Yes. No i cannot, it derives also home title with post title

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about what shows up in the tab bar in the browser page or like motivast said, in the the <title> tag? His suggesting is probably your best bet. SEO plugins are designed to allow you to modify the contents of your <title> tag to be specific to the page or the post in question.

Are you looking for uniform change on all pages and posts? That would be modifying the theme's default behavior though a function that modifies the output of wp_title(). https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/

Comment: @giodeutschland please give us something. Screenshot, theme name?

Comment: Both themes and plugins can affect your title tag, so unless you are able to share more details, we may not be able to help very effectively. :) Typically you can either use a filter on `wp_title()` (which will vary depending on what theme and plugins you're using), or you can create a child theme and adjust it there, if plugins aren't affecting it.

Comment: that is ym site: http://liebeundsprueche.com/liebeszitate/

Answer (score 1):

If I follow what you're explaining correctly, try adding a document title filter to the functions.php theme file. (NB: setting to only change post and pages. Search, Archive, etc, will keep original title. You can always modify accordingly.)

*** EDIT: added a filter for older themes that uses wp_title.

```
add_filter('wp_title', set_custom_page_title, 99999); //NB:backward compatibility with wp_title() theme function
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', set_custom_page_title, 99999);
function set_custom_page_title($orig_title) { 
    if(is_page() || is_single()){
        return get_the_title();
    }
    return $orig_title;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i updated my answer and please see my code, where should i add your code?

Comment: This code should be placed anywhere in a functions.php file in a child theme folder (and therefore avoid editing any core theme files.) If you don't have a child theme in place and just want to test this code out quickly, you can try adding this entire snippet right after the code you shown above. i.e. right after the line: add_filter( 'wp_title', 'heatmapthemead_wp_title', 10, 2 ); *** I suggest you back-up your theme files first.

Comment: I tried but i got fatal error.

Comment: i can show my site and theme and can u help me please? I have tried hundred plugins but doesn't work

Comment: Do you see a functions.php file within your theme folder... can you add the code snippet to the bottom of that file... NB: if there is a close php tag ?> at the end put the code snippet right before that. Try this and see if you still get a fatal error or not.

Comment: That is function php code. I wrote it in html input, please see
https://jsfiddle.net/o1a3x4qm/

Comment: Ok, I updated the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/o1a3x4qm/1/ Try update your functions.php file with it. If it gives n error, please let me know.

Comment: It doesn't give me error but also it doesn't change url
Please see  http://liebeundsprueche.com/liebeszitate/

Comment: Can you temporarily deactivate the Yoast SEO plugin and see if anything changes?

Comment: Okey, deactivated but no result. May be problem is in Theme? it use hooks ...

Comment: I guess we can check... can you paste the contents of header.php into jsfiddle? Only do that if you're sure you don't have anything confidential in the file, like passwords, emails, etc.

Comment: Okey problem solved. IT was about Allin seo pack, i deactivate it and everything it okey... thanks to much

Comment: Ok, cool. Good thing you decided to check that. Have a great day.